# Fatal error JRE when running JavaFX application (rezizing/scene change)

Tags: java, javafx, crash

i´m relatively new to Java and JavaFX and have this issue I can not figure out. Had it in all applications i´ve made so far.

This is my first Stackoverflow post so kindly give feedback if I missed something in my post.

The first app was a simple demo that switched between 2 scenes with a button. That app crashed every time it was trying to go back to the 1 scene again.

The latest app crashes when resizing the window. Every time.

Steps tried so far:

- Reinstalling JDE and JRE
- Same error using Eclipse Neon
- Updated graphics drivers
- Clearing HDD space
- Updating intelliJ

If someone has any clue what could be causing this I would be eternally grateful.

I will put the code and error report for the application crashing when resizing bellow:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
        primaryStage.isResizable();

        //grid
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));

        Scene scene = new Scene (grid,300,275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        //content
        Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL,20));

        Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
        grid.add(userName,0,1);

        TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextField,1,1);

        Label pw = new Label ("Password:");
        grid.add(pw,0,2);

        PasswordField pwField = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwField,1,2);


        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


-----------------------------------------------------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff941a898bc, pid=1748, tid=0x00000000000013a0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvd3dumx.dll+0x8098bc]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001a664000):  JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5024, stack(0x000000001add0000,0x000000001aed0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000030

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000001b5b5700, RCX=0x000000001b429000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000001aeceb10, RBP=0x0000000000000001, RSI=0x000000001aecec00, RDI=0x000000001aeceb60
R8 =0x0000000000000008, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000001aeceb60
R12=0x0000000000000001, R13=0x0000000000000001, R14=0x00000000008446a0, R15=0x00000000203a8c90
RIP=0x00007ff941a898bc, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001aeceb10)
0x000000001aeceb10:   0000000070787368 0000000000030324
0x000000001aeceb20:   00006f9e697364c0 0000000000000000
0x000000001aeceb30:   000000001b421b90 00007ff97d475729
0x000000001aeceb40:   00000000007bfb90 000000002026f2f0
0x000000001aeceb50:   000000002026f2f0 000000001aecebc0
0x000000001aeceb60:   00000000202a5d40 0000000000000000
0x000000001aeceb70:   0000012c00000000 0000000000000113
0x000000001aeceb80:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001aeceb90:   0000012c00000000 0000000000000113
0x000000001aeceba0:   0000000000000000 00007ff941a768b2
0x000000001aecebb0:   00006f9e697365f0 0000000000000000
0x000000001aecebc0:   00000000203a79d0 000000001aecece8
0x000000001aecebd0:   000000001aecec40 00007ff97224998e
0x000000001aecebe0:   00000000007bfb90 00007ff941a77690
0x000000001aecebf0:   00000000007bfb90 00000000202a5d40
0x000000001aecec00:   000000001aecedb0 0000000000000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ff941a898bc)
0x00007ff941a8989c:   00 00 38 90 72 16 00 00 74 22 48 8b 01 81 b8 0c
0x00007ff941a898ac:   02 00 00 00 21 00 00 72 13 48 8b 47 20 0f b6 d2
0x00007ff941a898bc:   8b 48 30 c1 e9 03 40 84 cd 0f 45 d5 f7 47 40 00
0x00007ff941a898cc:   04 00 00 0f 85 66 01 00 00 84 d2 0f 85 5e 01 00 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000001b5b5700 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000001b429000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001aeceb10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a664000
RBP=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000001aecec00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a664000
RDI=0x000000001aeceb60 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a664000
R8 =0x0000000000000008 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000001aeceb60 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a664000
R12=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R14=0x00000000008446a0 is an unknown value
R15=0x00000000203a8c90 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000001add0000,0x000000001aed0000],  sp=0x000000001aeceb10,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nvd3dumx.dll+0x8098bc]
C  [lci_proxyumd.dll+0x5729]
C  [d3d9.dll+0x998e]
C  [d3d9.dll+0x9204]
C  [d3d9.dll+0xbc68]
C  [prism_d3d.dll+0x4b62]
C  0x0000000002877f74

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DSwapChain.nPresent(JJ)I+0
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DSwapChain.present()Z+16
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run()V+446
j  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset()Z+47
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run()V+1
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run()V+8
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001a7fa800 JavaThread "Prism Font Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6652, stack(0x0000000022360000,0x0000000022460000)]
  0x000000001a75f800 JavaThread "JavaFX-Launcher" [_thread_blocked, id=8304, stack(0x0000000020ed0000,0x0000000020fd0000)]
  0x000000001a716800 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8176, stack(0x0000000020dd0000,0x0000000020ed0000)]
  0x000000001a6d2000 JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=11276, stack(0x000000001c0e0000,0x000000001c1e0000)]
  0x000000001a6c4000 JavaThread "Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1400, stack(0x000000001bfe0000,0x000000001c0e0000)]
=>0x000000001a664000 JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5024, stack(0x000000001add0000,0x000000001aed0000)]
  0x000000001985e800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12108, stack(0x000000001a3d0000,0x000000001a4d0000)]
  0x00000000197c2000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6436, stack(0x000000001a2d0000,0x000000001a3d0000)]
  0x00000000197b4000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9856, stack(0x000000001a1d0000,0x000000001a2d0000)]
  0x0000000019754000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8044, stack(0x000000001a0d0000,0x000000001a1d0000)]
  0x0000000019753000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6740, stack(0x0000000019fd0000,0x000000001a0d0000)]
  0x00000000197b1800 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10084, stack(0x0000000019ed0000,0x0000000019fd0000)]
  0x000000001970b800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9952, stack(0x0000000019dd0000,0x0000000019ed0000)]
  0x000000001970a800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12584, stack(0x0000000019cd0000,0x0000000019dd0000)]
  0x0000000019700800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=232, stack(0x0000000019ae0000,0x0000000019be0000)]
  0x0000000002857800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6868, stack(0x00000000195e0000,0x00000000196e0000)]
  0x000000000265e000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=9488, stack(0x0000000002460000,0x0000000002560000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000177e9800 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000194e0000,0x00000000195e0000] [id=8784]
  0x0000000019864800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001a4d0000,0x000000001a5d0000] [id=5756]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 11575K [0x00000000d5e00000, 0x00000000d8880000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 24% used [0x00000000d5e00000,0x00000000d65fd3a8,0x00000000d7e80000)
  from space 5120K, 66% used [0x00000000d7e80000,0x00000000d81d0ad0,0x00000000d8380000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8880000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 16K [0x0000000081a00000, 0x0000000086f80000, 0x00000000d5e00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081a00000,0x0000000081a04000,0x0000000086f80000)
 Metaspace       used 14679K, capacity 15288K, committed 15616K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 2048K, capacity 2204K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011c20000,0x0000000012020000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011813000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000055a6c720
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012ad0000, 0x0000000014a68000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014a68000, 0x0000000016a00000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000cb0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=6491Kb max_used=6502Kb free=239268Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002860000, 0x0000000002ec0000, 0x0000000011860000]
 total_blobs=2780 nmethods=2153 adapters=538
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 17.052 Thread 0x00000000197c2000 2149       1       com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DContext::getContextHandle (5 bytes)
Event: 17.052 Thread 0x00000000197c2000 nmethod 2149 0x0000000002eb6b50 code [0x0000000002eb6ca0, 0x0000000002eb6db0]
Event: 17.231 Thread 0x0000000019754000 2150   !   4       java.util.WeakHashMap::expungeStaleEntries (139 bytes)
Event: 17.260 Thread 0x0000000019754000 nmethod 2150 0x0000000002eba3d0 code [0x0000000002eba540, 0x0000000002ebaef8]
Event: 17.887 Thread 0x00000000197b4000 2151       4       com.sun.javafx.font.CompositeStrike::getStrikeSlot (165 bytes)
Event: 17.887 Thread 0x00000000197c2000 2152       3       com.sun.javafx.geom.RectBounds::intersectWith (86 bytes)
Event: 17.888 Thread 0x0000000019753000 2153       4       com.sun.javafx.text.TextRun::getGlyphCode (46 bytes)
Event: 17.888 Thread 0x00000000197b4000 nmethod 2151 0x0000000002eb74d0 code [0x0000000002eb7600, 0x0000000002eb7698]
Event: 17.889 Thread 0x00000000197c2000 nmethod 2152 0x0000000002eb99d0 code [0x0000000002eb9b80, 0x0000000002eba218]
Event: 17.890 Thread 0x0000000019753000 nmethod 2153 0x0000000002eb7150 code [0x0000000002eb72a0, 0x0000000002eb7398]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 4.257 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 33280K [0x00000000d5e00000, 0x00000000d8880000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000d5e00000,0x00000000d7e80000,0x00000000d7e80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8880000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7e80000,0x00000000d7e80000,0x00000000d8380000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081a00000, 0x0000000086f80000, 0x00000000d5e00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081a00000,0x0000000081a00000,0x0000000086f80000)
 Metaspace       used 13414K, capacity 13948K, committed 14208K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1985K, capacity 2132K, committed 2176K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 4.269 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 3394K [0x00000000d5e00000, 0x00000000d8880000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 0% used [0x00000000d5e00000,0x00000000d5e00000,0x00000000d7e80000)
  from space 5120K, 66% used [0x00000000d7e80000,0x00000000d81d0ad0,0x00000000d8380000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8880000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 16K [0x0000000081a00000, 0x0000000086f80000, 0x00000000d5e00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081a00000,0x0000000081a04000,0x0000000086f80000)
 Metaspace       used 13414K, capacity 13948K, committed 14208K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1985K, capacity 2132K, committed 2176K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 3.462 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029fa630 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 3.462 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029fa630 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 3.462 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029fa630 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 3.625 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029fa630 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 4.029 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002b0518c method=sun.net.www.ParseUtil.encodePath(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/String; @ 109
Event: 4.068 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002b50140 method=sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen()V @ 4
Event: 4.233 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002ba7a68 method=jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Type.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes(Ljava/lang/String;)I @ 47
Event: 8.127 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002cc0ac4 method=com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.KeyBinding.getSpecificity(Ljavafx/scene/control/Control;Ljavafx/scene/input/KeyEvent;)I @ 35
Event: 8.145 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002d23b60 method=java.util.WeakHashMap.expungeStaleEntries()V @ 9
Event: 8.463 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000029f0140 method=java.lang.CharacterData.of(I)Ljava/lang/CharacterData; @ 4

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.908 Thread 0x000000000265e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000d6224f78) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 1.005 Thread 0x000000000265e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d62d0bb0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 1.005 Thread 0x000000000265e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d62d0dc0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 1.008 Thread 0x000000000265e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d62d4cd0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 1.008 Thread 0x000000000265e000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d62d4ee0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 1.009 Thread 0x000000000265e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000d62d58e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1197]
Event: 1.090 Thread 0x000000000265e000 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000029850d5 to 0x00000000029852a1
Event: 2.299 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000d6ddf5d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1197]
Event: 2.299 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000d6ddf5d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1394]
Event: 4.068 Thread 0x000000001a6d2000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002b4f06e to 0x0000000002b50119

Events (10 events):
Event: 8.463 loading class java/lang/CharacterData00
Event: 8.464 loading class java/lang/CharacterData00 done
Event: 8.464 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize
Event: 8.465 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize done
Event: 17.028 loading class com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/QuantumToolkit
Event: 17.028 loading class com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/QuantumToolkit done
Event: 17.028 loading class com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/QuantumToolkit
Event: 17.028 loading class com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/QuantumToolkit done
Event: 17.030 loading class com/sun/javafx/tk/RenderJob
Event: 17.030 loading class com/sun/javafx/tk/RenderJob done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff61b560000 - 0x00007ff61b597000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff9859c0000 - 0x00007ff985b91000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff982f60000 - 0x00007ff98300c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff982d30000 - 0x00007ff982f4d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff985030000 - 0x00007ff9850d2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff984e60000 - 0x00007ff984efe000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff985270000 - 0x00007ff9852c9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff984f00000 - 0x00007ff985021000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff985850000 - 0x00007ff9859b5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff9827e0000 - 0x00007ff9827fe000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ff985150000 - 0x00007ff985184000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff981eb0000 - 0x00007ff982032000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ff978230000 - 0x00007ff9784aa000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.14393.953_none_42151e83c686086b\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff984b90000 - 0x00007ff984e58000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff982b20000 - 0x00007ff982c15000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ff982770000 - 0x00007ff9827da000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff984590000 - 0x00007ff9845be000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000056d20000 - 0x0000000056df2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000055250000 - 0x0000000055aec000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff985200000 - 0x00007ff985208000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff9800c0000 - 0x00007ff9800e3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff974df0000 - 0x00007ff974df9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff9850e0000 - 0x00007ff98514a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x0000000000c80000 - 0x0000000000cab000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff982040000 - 0x00007ff982082000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ff97b8c0000 - 0x00007ff97b8ca000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000056d10000 - 0x0000000056d1f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000056ce0000 - 0x0000000056d09000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000056cb0000 - 0x0000000056cd3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x0000000056c90000 - 0x0000000056ca6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff983020000 - 0x00007ff984528000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff982090000 - 0x00007ff98276a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ff981e60000 - 0x00007ff981eac000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ff984b30000 - 0x00007ff984b82000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ff981e50000 - 0x00007ff981e5f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff982800000 - 0x00007ff9828a9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ff981e30000 - 0x00007ff981e44000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff971530000 - 0x00007ff97154a000     C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.2\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x0000000056c70000 - 0x0000000056c8a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ff981750000 - 0x00007ff9817ac000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ff961f20000 - 0x00007ff96200f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcr120.dll
0x00007ff960920000 - 0x00007ff9609c6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcp120.dll
0x0000000056c40000 - 0x0000000056c62000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\prism_d3d.dll
0x00007ff972240000 - 0x00007ff9723cd000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
0x00007ff97f960000 - 0x00007ff97f986000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ff9804f0000 - 0x00007ff980585000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ff943730000 - 0x00007ff945c6d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\igdumdim64.dll
0x00007ff9855f0000 - 0x00007ff9856af000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ff9828b0000 - 0x00007ff98294c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ff9845c0000 - 0x00007ff9846f8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x00007ff984700000 - 0x00007ff984b29000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ff95ce10000 - 0x00007ff95cfe5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvspcap64.dll
0x00007ff97f110000 - 0x00007ff97f1dd000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
0x00007ff97e8d0000 - 0x00007ff97e8e3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9779c0000 - 0x00007ff977dde000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvapi64.dll
0x00007ff980da0000 - 0x00007ff980e3f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
0x0000000056bf0000 - 0x0000000056c33000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\glass.dll
0x00007ff985750000 - 0x00007ff98584a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\COMDLG32.dll
0x00007ff985470000 - 0x00007ff9855ca000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ff97d470000 - 0x00007ff97d49f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\lci_proxyumd.dll
0x00007ff941280000 - 0x00007ff94228a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvami.inf_amd64_79f909bfbbd7ec05\nvd3dumx.dll
0x0000000056bb0000 - 0x0000000056bc4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\javafx_font.dll
0x00007ff973f50000 - 0x00007ff9741b9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll
0x00007ff9856b0000 - 0x00007ff98574f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ff97e400000 - 0x00007ff97e5a8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x00007ff9717e0000 - 0x00007ff971829000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dataexchange.dll
0x00007ff97e930000 - 0x00007ff97ebe6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d11.dll
0x00007ff97fec0000 - 0x00007ff980011000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dcomp.dll
0x00007ff980870000 - 0x00007ff98098c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
0x00007ff981a00000 - 0x00007ff981a2b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ff96cb80000 - 0x00007ff96cbb2000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\rtscom.dll
0x0000000056b90000 - 0x0000000056ba1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\prism_common.dll
0x00007ff97b340000 - 0x00007ff97b4d2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=56284:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: sample.Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Ett\IdeaProjects\untitled4\out\production\untitled4;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Windows\hh.exe C:\Users\Ett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\Ett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Ett\AppData\Roaming\npm
USERNAME=Ett
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 14393 (10.0.14393.1198)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 8275056k(3164292k free), swap 9585776k(3014952k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed May 17 22:21:28 2017
elapsed time: 17 seconds (0d 0h 0m 17s)
```

Comment: The Program looks fine to me. Probably, specific to your computer.

Comment: Can anyone figure out what this means? # Problematic frame:
# C  [nvd3dumx.dll+0x8120dc] Does the error have with my Nvidia drivers to do?

Comment: It means the code crashes while executing something in that library, but that does not tell you much I'm afraid. You can see the stack trace of java calls that lead to there. I found a similar stack trace in [this JRE bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8115461), but that was fixed 4 years ago, and your Java version is very recent. Updating graphics drivers was a good idea. Maybe you have other stuff installed that interferes with the driver... Difficult to say.

Comment: To me it looks like a driver issue... maybe try rolling back to an older version and try to find one that works? Another thing to try is to run the program with `-Dprism.order=sw` to force software-rendering, bypassing the GPU drivers...

Comment: Thank you so much! the software-rendering was the perfect workaround and it works flawlessly. Might search for a more permanent solution later but this is excellent for now.

Comment: Please consider submitting this at the OpenJDK as a possible bug in JavaFX: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by reseting Windows 10. So the issue was not caused by IntelliJ or JavaFX. More likely due to my modding of the windows UI.